# Nodes connected incorrectly in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to achieve the following:

[image]

But the connecting of nodes isn't working properly. I get the following output:

[image]

How do I fix this and where am I going wrong.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{square/.style = {
    shape  = rectangle,
    fill   = gray!50,
    draw   = black,
    thick
}}

\tikzset{circle/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    fill   = blue!20,
    draw   = blue,
    thick
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[square] (-4,4)rectangle node (r1) {r1} (-3,5);
  \draw[circle] (-1,4.5) circle [radius=0.5cm] node (s1) {s1};
  \draw[->] (r1.west) -- (s1.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please note that I would like to stick to the approach of `\draw[->] (r1.west) -- (s1.east);`

Comment: @JouleV thanks. In that case when to use `(r1.west) -- (s1.east);` and when to use `(r1)--(s1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Correct picture

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{squarenode/.style = {
    shape  = rectangle,
    fill   = gray!50,
    draw   = black,
    thick,
    minimum size=1cm %%%% Take note of this!
},
    circlenode/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    fill   = blue!20,
    draw   = blue,
    thick,
    minimum size=1cm %%%% and this!
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-4,4.5) node[squarenode] (r1) {r1}; % Or \node[squarenode] (r1) at (-4,4.5) {r1};
  \draw (-1,4.5) node[circlenode] (s1) {s1}; % Or \node[circlenode] (s1) at (-1,4.5) {s1};
  \draw[->] (r1) -- (s1); % or (r1.east)--(s1.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Some notes (important!)

1. `circle` is a defined option, therefore you must not define a new `circle`. I changed it to `circlenode`.
2. You don't have to draw the circle and the square manually. You can use the shape in the node and `minimum size`. For more controlling, we have `minimum height` and `minimum width`.
3. I don't recommend using many `\tikzset{}`s.
4. `tikz` is not an option of `article`. It is an option of `standalone`. When you load `tikz` option already, you don't need `\usepackage{tikz}`.

#### Difference when you use `(r1)--(s1)` and `(r1.east)--(s1.west)`

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {Some text};
\node[draw] (b) at (5,3) {Hello world};
\draw[thick] (0,0)--(5,3);
\draw[red] (a)--(b);
\draw[blue] (a.east)--(b.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Look closely at the beginning point and the ending point of the red line and the blue line.