# Nodes connected incorrectly in TikZ - continued

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is a follow up of the question [Nodes connected incorrectly in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477557/nodes-connected-incorrectly-in-tikz)
.

With the approach suggested by the accepted answer in that question, when I used the logic in my original code, the output wasn't the same.

I get something like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{square/.style = {
    shape  = rectangle,
    fill   = gray!50,
    draw   = black,
    thick
}}

\tikzset{circle/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    fill   = blue!20,
    draw   = blue,
    thick
}}

\tikzset{help lines/.style=very thin}
\tikzset{My Grid/.style={help lines,color=blue!50}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  %\draw[My Grid] (-5,-5) grid (15,15);
  \draw[square] (-4,4)rectangle node (r1) {r1} (-3,5);
  \draw[square] (1,4) rectangle node (r2) {r2} (2,5);
  \draw[square] (-3,0) rectangle node (r3) {r3} (-4,1);
  \draw[square] (1,0) rectangle node (r4) {r4} (2,1);
  \draw[circle] (-1,2.5) circle [radius=0.5cm] node[above=2ex,red] (s) {$s \leq 3$};
  \draw[circle] (-1,4.5) circle [radius=0.5cm] node (s1) {s1};
  \draw[circle] (-1,6.5) circle [radius=0.5cm] node (s2) {};
  \draw[fill=black] (-1,6.5) circle [radius=0.1cm] node (s3) {};
  \draw[circle] (-1,0.5) circle [radius=0.5cm] node (s4) {s4};
  \draw[circle] (-1,-1.5) circle [radius=0.5cm] node (s5) {};
  \draw[fill=black] (-1,-1.5) circle [radius=0.1cm];
  \draw[->] (r1) -- (s1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Read my answer _carefully_, I mentioned about this. I quote this sentence: "You don't have to draw the circle and the square manually. You can use the shape in the node and `minimum size`. For more controlling, we have `minimum height` and `minimum width`."

Comment: If you draw the circle and the rectangle by the coordinates, you _have to_ draw the arrows by using coordinates, not the node names, because the rectangles and the circles are _not_ related to the nodes at all. Btw, you are not actually using the changes I made in that answer, as I can see.

Comment: you should clarify, what you like to achieve. for basic how to use `tikz` you should read *tikz & pgf manual*, it is huge, however for start it is suficient to read some tutorials or part 3: *tikz ist kein Zaichenprogram*. btw, your approach drawing nodes is unusual and unnecessary complicated ...

Comment: @zarko can you please clarify how is it complicated

Comment: @joulev yes I saw the changes.  But that would require a lot of changes and wanted to know how will things work with my code

Comment: see last example provided in @JouleV answer on your previous question. it simple, short and clear.

Comment: @Zarko If it were so simple and clear, our friend *subham soni* would have understood it, wouldn't he?

Comment: @AndréC So it is neither simple nor clear nor short nor easy nor good. However, our friend subham soni seems to be working on a much more complicated code.

Comment: @JouleV Are you saying that if he doesn't understand, it's his fault?

Comment: @AndréC Then I can't figure out why he accepted my answer. I would like to see your answer there. I love simple things.

Comment: @JouleV He accepted your answer because it solved the problem. That does not prevent him from not understanding it, otherwise he would not have asked a second question.

Comment: @AndréC In SE, "accept" means "helpful". If he didn't understand my answer, he would not accept it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90537/discussion-between-andrec-and-joulev).

Answer (score 3):

The graphic you want to create is exactly the same as the one created in the tutorial **A Petri-Net for Hagen in manual** 3.1.1 on pages 49 to 60.

I invite you to read it, it is very well written and very complete.

Here is the complete code of the manual figure given on page 52:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[place/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=6mm},
transition/.style={rectangle,draw=black!50,fill=black!20,thick,
inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4mm}]
\node[place] (waiting) {};
\node[place] (critical) [below=of waiting] {};
\node[place] (semaphore) [below=of critical] {};
\node[transition] (leave critical) [right=of critical] {};
\node[transition] (enter critical) [left=of critical] {};
\draw [->] (enter critical.east) -- (critical.west);
\draw [->] (waiting.west) .. controls +(left:5mm) and +(up:5mm)
.. (enter critical.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Here is the final figure built at the end of the tutorial.

[image: screenshot-2]

Comment: yes I am following the same book. But I don't want to copy the code directly.  I want to use my existing learning and learn . Copying the code will block me from learning.  That's why.

Comment: Take the time to read this tutorial, it explains everything in a methodical and educational way. You will understand what a `node` is and what causes you problems.

Answer (score 3):

Define your elements directly as a `\node`. This way you can define anchor points on your elements. If I show this way using part of your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{square/.style = {
    shape  = rectangle,
    fill   = gray!50,
    draw   = black,
    minimum height=1cm,
    minimum width=1cm,
    thick
}}

\tikzset{circle/.style = {
    shape  = circle,
    fill   = blue!20,
    draw   = blue,
    minimum size=1cm,
    inner sep=0pt,
    thick
}}

\tikzset{help lines/.style=very thin}
\tikzset{My Grid/.style={help lines,color=blue!50}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  %\draw[My Grid] (-5,-5) grid (15,15);
  \node (r1) at (-3.5,4.5) [square] {r1};
  \node (s1)at (-1,4.5) [circle]{s1};
  \draw[->] (r1) -- (s1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[xshift=2cm]
  %\draw[My Grid] (-5,-5) grid (15,15);
  \node (r1) at (-3.5,4.5) [square] {r1};
  \node (s1)at (-1,4.5) [circle]{s1};
  \draw[->] (r1.east) -- (s1.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[xshift=2cm]
  %\draw[My Grid] (-5,-5) grid (15,15);
  \node (r1) at (-3.5,4.5) [square] {r1};
  \node (s1)at (-1,4.5) [circle]{s1};
  \draw[->] (r1.south east) -- (s1.180);
  \draw[->] (r1.north east) -- (s1.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]